# HTML5/Javascript: how to get real size/position of a 3D transformed div?

Tags: html, 3d

I wonder if someone can help me resolving this problem:

I have a DIV,
I apply 3d transform on it to rotate it and translate it in the 3d space.

Now: how can I get the REAL (on screen, 2D) position and size of that transformed DIV?

thanks all